# É possível migrar um sistema web2py para django mantendo o mesmo banco de dados?

Tags: aplicação-web, django, web2py

É possível migrar um sistema web em produção feito em web2py para um refeito em django, mantendo o mesmo banco de dados? 
Estou com um sistema feito em **web2py** (em produção) e preciso refazê-lo em **django**, mantendo o *mesmo banco de dados*. O problema é que o django e o web2py têm sistemas diferentes de tabelas para usuários. 
Portanto, o banco de dados em produção possui as tabelas de usuário do web2py, enquanto no django criam-se por padrão várias tabelas (sendo a de usuário apenas uma delas).
Como eu consigo fazer o django funcionar (com sistema de autenticação) utilizando um banco de dados já pronto de um sistema feito em web2py?

Desde já, agradeço a atenção de todos!

P.S.: o BD original foi feito em postgreSQL.

Comment: Não conheço Web2py e não sei qual a estrutura de tabelas criada para autenticação. Talvez se você colocasse um print do schema talvez ficasse mais fácil apontar uma solução.

Answer (score 0):

O Django possui uma ferramenta chamada [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) que pode criar os modelos introspectando o banco de dados existente. Você pode verificar a saida rodando este comando:

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb
```

Salve-o como um arquivo:

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Uma vez que tenha limpado seus modelos, nomeie arquivo `models.py` e coloque-o no pacote Python que contém sua aplicação. Então adicione a app dentro da sua definição de INSTALLED_APPS.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'CENSUS_PERSONS'
```

A seguir, execute as devidas migrações:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Além disso, poderá mapear o banco manualmente no `models.py`, gerar um [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-pt.html) do seu banco legado e finalmente usar o comando [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/ref/django-admin/#loaddata) para carregar seu banco no Django:

```
$ django-admin loaddata mydata.json
```

veja mais sobre o loaddata e também dumpdata [aqui](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata).